# Access variables of a regression model in R

Tags: r, statistics

I am working with a linear model, say

```
y<-rnorm(20)
x1<-rgamma(20,2,1)
x2<-rpois(20,3)

fit<-lm(y~x1*x2)
summary(fit)
```

and I was wondering, is there a way to access the regression variables through `lm`? One option would be to simply use

`fit$model`

and what you get is

```
             y        x1 x2
1   1.52366782 1.1741392  4
2  -0.23640711 0.8780224  2
3   0.90728028 3.2192029  3
4  -0.07964816 2.5476499  3
5  -0.50999322 1.8515032  2
6   0.08854942 0.2892199  1
7   0.19708785 1.1865428  3
8   0.09641827 0.5808471  1
9  -0.28815596 1.3589239  1
10 -0.45784790 3.7514056  2
11 -0.39785151 0.8648221  0
12 -0.17503763 0.8153766  3
13  1.44095562 0.1933351  1
14 -0.86787846 2.7348324  5
15  0.30369142 0.7547339  7
16 -0.76884945 2.1558952  1
17 -0.81620973 1.2373447  3
18 -0.40978079 1.2046777  2
19 -0.23160424 1.8455335  2
20  2.90504457 0.9968425  2
```

and then the response is displayed along with the covariates. The problem is that the interaction `x1:x2` *is not* there and it is often an important part of model building.

The problem arises in the context of variable selection when stepwise procedures reduce a huge dataset into a few variables and their interactions. I would like to build the covariate matrix for this model with no reference to the dataset.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Maybe have a look at [broom](https://github.com/dgrtwo/broom) package.

Comment: I don't understand the closing vote. This is a legit question and I have supplied a minimal working example.

Comment: @zx8754 If  you like, you can illustrate the way to do that in an answer so I can mark it as correct.

Comment: How about `vcov(fit)`? I don't fully understand your requirements, could you add expected output to your post?

Comment: The `x1:x2` is, in math notation, x1*x2 so all the information is there.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik Yes but that means having to identify the terms on my own. I was hoping for a more automated procedure for the case of 10 or 15 such terms.

Comment: How about `s <- summary(fit); mymod <- paste(attr(s$terms, "term.labels"), collapse=" + ");
model.matrix(formula(paste("~", mymod)), data=fit$model)`

Comment: @user20650 Amazing, thank you so much. I insist that you post that as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to Roland

You can get the model string by accessing the summary attributes (have a look at `str(s)`)

```
s <- summary(fit)
mymod <- paste(attr(s$terms, "term.labels"), collapse=" + ")
mymod
[1] "x1 + x2 + x1:x2"
```

However, you can get the data by passing the model fit to `model.matrix`

```
model.matrix(fit)
```

There will be a bit of extra work if you have `factor` variables.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Whenever you have some free time, I would be grateful if you could explain a little bit your steps for the benefit of the unitiated. It definitely works though.

Comment: This seems awfully complicated. Just use `model.matrix(fit)`.

Comment: @Roland; ugh ... oh dear